# How do I install HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 2510 All-in-One Series?

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp

Ubuntu 12.04 has the version 3.12.2-1ubuntu3.1 and http://sourceforge.net/news/index.php?group_id=149981&limit=5&offset=5 says that HP DeskJet 2510 All-in-One Series is supported in HPLIP version 3.12.6.

How do I get this printer working?

Answer (score 1):

Download HPLIP from http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html.

BTW it says:

> You have selected Ubuntu 12.04 using the HP Deskjet 2050 j510 All-in-one Printer.
>
> Ubuntu 12.04 supplies HPLIP 3.12.2 and it does support your printer.
>
> As the version of HPLIP supplied with your operating system supports your printer, you >may continue to use that version of HPLIP.
>
> You may now optionally download the latest version of HPLIP to get access to new features >and bug fixes.

Comment: My question was a bit inaccurate.. I was hoping for more ppa style solution. But the hplip installer does the job.

Comment: There was hplip ppa, but it's no longer updated.